# What's the name of the little number or symbol that refers you to a footnote?

Tags: single-word-requests, footnotes

The word footnote seems to only refer to the actual text that you are brought to if you follow the little number or symbol (such as '*') to the bottom of the page.

Does the actual superscript character have a name?

Comment: In mathematics aren't they called "index numbers"?

Comment: It is a "reference". In computer technology it is a "link".

Comment: Have to tried to find the answer looking around on the web?

Comment: @WeatherVane The *use* of the number/symbol is a reference, not the number/symbol itself. Just like "WeatherVane" is not a reference (it's your name/handle), but your name can be used *in reference* to you or *to reference* you. See [the definition of "reference"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reference). The accepted answer makes this distinction correctly, using "reference" as a modifier, not the name of the thing itself. See also what "reference" is used for in this description: http://printwiki.org/Footnote

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, **reference mark** is in the dictionary to refer to the symbols:

> any of various written or printed symbols, as an asterisk (*), dagger (†), or superscript number, used to indicate the presence of further information in a footnote, bibliography, or other text.
>   
>   <sub>[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reference-mark) Unabridged
>
>   Based on the Random House Dictionary, © Random House, Inc. 2018.</sub>

Another similar phrase that is used is [reference symbol](http://www.brl.org/codes/session04/reference.html).

The corresponding phrase for a number would be a **reference number**:

> A footnote consists of two linked parts: the footnote reference number that appears in text, and the footnote text that appears at the bottom of the column.
>   <sub>[Create footnotes in InDesign - Adobe Support](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/footnotes.html)</sub>

And then there's [footnote number](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/04/) and [footnote symbol](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/its/help/faq?faqid=311).

Comment: See also http://printwiki.org/Footnote, which calls them **reference marks**.